# ScatterPlot PlotXY NI - Performence

Tags: c#, performance, graph, plot, scatter-plot

I use the **PlotXY** function of `ScatterPlot` (NI):

```
scatterPlot.PlotXY(XValues.ToArray(),Values.ToArray());
```

When I have a really large data, it works very slow.

The graph is updated slowly, and besides **all the program hangs**.

I read in a few places that it works slow with large data, I wanted to know if there a way to **improve** the performance of PlotXY?